# In Linux/C programming, using the function write moves the indicator on the buffer too?

Tags: c, linux, file, buffer, fwrite

If i use a text file as a buffer, calling:

```
write(fd1, *buffer, count)
write(fd2, *buffer, count)
```

will write the same datas on both fd1 and fd2 from buffer or the write on fd2 will start from the point of the buffer where the write on fd1 finished?

(lurking a lot here, first time asking something, sorry if i did/wrote something wrong)

Comment: from the documentation, http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/fwrite/ , `ptr` is converted to a `const void*`. It is therefore likely that the same thing will be written in both files

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming `*buffer` results in a pointer to an object that contains at least `count` bytes, and that `fd1` and `fd2` are valid file descriptors, then the code you have presented will pass the same pointer value and count to each call to `write()`. `write()` will not alter the contents in any way, and the pass by value semantics of function calls would prevent it from modifying the pointer. The only way for the pointer value to be changed would be if `write()` was somehow defined to be a macro on your system.

Assuming `write()` is not a macro, even though each call passes the same arguments, each call may have ended up writing a different number of bytes. You have to check the return value of `write()` to see how many bytes of the `*buffer` was written.

Answer (score 0):

Written bytes will be the same: http://linux.die.net/man/2/write (pay attention to `const char*` type of buffer).

Answer (score 0):

write() function is used to write to file descriptor passed as argument, another argument is of type const char*, (in this case the buffer), which means it doesn't change. until the value in buffer is explicitly modified by user for example `strncpy(buffer,"bye",3)` fd1 and fd2 will both have same values written to them.